# ST_Distance Webmercator Error

Tags: carto, web-mercator

When applying the following query to my javascript I get this error:

```
SELECT c.addressno,
 ST_Distance(c.the_geom, 
 (SELECT the_geom FROM test_alignment_poly ORDER BY the_geom <-> c.the_geom LIMIT 1))
 as MinDistance FROM address_pt_subset c where c.addressno='8635'
```

{"error":["column \"the_geom\" does not exist"]}

After some research I found [cartodb projections](http://developers.cartodb.com/tutorials/projections.html) tutorial after applying the following information I was able to get the following query to work on the map view of the dash board:

```
SELECT c.addressno,the_geom_webmercator,cartodb_id,ST_Distance(c.the_geom,(SELECT     
  the_geom FROM test_alignment_poly ORDER BY the_geom <-> c.the_geom LIMIT 1))as  
  MinDistance FROM address_pt_subset c where c.addressno='8635'
```

Though as stated above when applying the same query to the API I still get a geom error.

Is the nested geom value causing the error?

I have tried many variation of transforming both geom values without success. I feel like I am close but I have run out of ideas.

Comment: Are you sure you have a column called "the_geom" in test_alignment_poly?

Comment: Yes I do have a column called the_geom  in both tables

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with the particular error you are getting or where in the system you are getting it. But try adding it to your result set and see what happens

```
SELECT 
  addressno,
  the_geom_webmercator,
  the_geom,
  cartodb_id,
  ST_Distance(
    the_geom,
    (SELECT the_geom FROM test_alignment_poly ORDER BY the_geom <-> c.the_geom LIMIT 1)
  ) as MinDistance 
FROM address_pt_subset c 
WHERE c.addressno='8635'
```

If you have any the_geom = NULL you may run into issues as well. In which case, try this,

```
SELECT 
  addressno,
  the_geom_webmercator,
  the_geom,
  cartodb_id,
  ST_Distance(
    the_geom,
    (SELECT the_geom FROM test_alignment_poly ORDER BY the_geom <-> c.the_geom LIMIT 1)
  ) as MinDistance 
FROM address_pt_subset c 
WHERE c.addressno='8635'
AND the_geom IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest adding the_geom to one of the elements in your SELECT statement.  I have found that if I don't select the_geom as part of my query from the API, I will get that response.  Not sure if that is a bug in the API, it is by design, or I'm completely wrong.  More than likely, it's the latter!

Comment: It ended up being a syntax error though I am not sure why I was still receiving a the_geom error.